# runner's successcallback never called

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js, e2e-testing

I'm trying to run my nightwatch tests from a node script.

```js
const nightwatch = require('nightwatch');


const configOptions = {
  config: 'nightwatch.conf.js',
  env: 'local'
};

nightwatch.runner(configOptions, function() {
  console.log('done!');
});
```

Everything is woking fine, all tests run properly.
But the callback function is not called. nightwatch keeps idling, have to kill it manually.

This is not happening when I run the tests via nightwatch cli.

I have no clue. Someone got an idea?
Thanks in advance

EDIT:
The nightwatch.conf.js file:

```js
var seleniumServerStandalone = require('selenium-server-standalone-jar');
var geckoDriver = require('geckodriver');
var chromeDriver = require('chromedriver');

var SELENIUM_CONFIGURATION = {
  start_process: true,
  server_path: seleniumServerStandalone.path,
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 4444,
  cli_args : {
    'webdriver.chrome.driver' : chromeDriver.path,
    'webdriver.gecko.driver': geckoDriver.path
  }
};

var FIREFOX_CONFIGURATION = {
  browserName: 'firefox',
  javascriptEnabled: true,
  acceptSslCerts: true,
  elementScrollBehavior: 1
};

var CHROME_CONFIGURATION = {
  browserName: 'chrome',
  javascriptEnabled: true,
  acceptSslCerts: true,
  elementScrollBehavior: 1,
  chromeOptions : {
    args: ['window-size=1400,800']
  }
};

var LIVE_ENV_VARS = {
  validLoginCredentials: {
    mail: 'valid-user@mail.net',
    password: "validpw"
  },
  invalidLoginCredentials: {
    mail: 'invalid-user@mail.net',
    password: "invalidpw"
  },
  startUrl: 'https://app.hrlab.de'
};

var LOCAL_ENV_VARS = {
  validLoginCredentials: {
    mail: 'valid-user@mail.net',
    password: "validpw"
  },
  invalidLoginCredentials: {
    mail: 'invalid-user@mail.net',
    password: "invalidpw"
  },
  startUrl: 'http://127.0.0.1:3333'
};

var STABLE_VARS = {
  reasonableWait: 2000,
  reasonableRender: 20000
};

var DEFAULT_CONFIGURATION = {
  launch_url: 'http://localhost',
  selenium_port: 4444,
  selenium_host: 'localhost',
  desiredCapabilities: CHROME_CONFIGURATION,
  globals: {
    environment: LIVE_ENV_VARS,
    stable: STABLE_VARS
  }
};

var LOCAL_CONFIGURATION = {
  launch_url: 'http://localhost:3333',
  selenium_port: 4444,
  selenium_host: 'localhost',
  desiredCapabilities: CHROME_CONFIGURATION,
  globals: {
    environment: LOCAL_ENV_VARS,
    stable: STABLE_VARS
  }
};

var LOCAL_CONFIGURATION_FIREFOX = {
  launch_url: 'http://localhost:3333',
  selenium_port: 4444,
  selenium_host: 'localhost',
  desiredCapabilities: FIREFOX_CONFIGURATION,
  globals: {
    environment: LOCAL_ENV_VARS,
    stable: STABLE_VARS
  }
};


var ENVIRONMENTS = {
  default: DEFAULT_CONFIGURATION,
  local: LOCAL_CONFIGURATION,
  local_firefox: LOCAL_CONFIGURATION_FIREFOX
};

module.exports = {
  src_folders: ['test/e2e'],
  page_objects_path: 'test/e2e/page_objects',
  selenium: SELENIUM_CONFIGURATION,
  test_settings: ENVIRONMENTS
};
```

Comment: What is in your configuration file?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I added my config to my post.
Again, the tests run well and the problem of the idling nightwatch runner doesn't occure when invoked via cli.